# MySQL Select from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL. I am creating a checkout page in PHP. When the users select the items they want to buy and click "Add to Cart", a temporary table gets created which has the following fields (table name is temp):

```
+--------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Cart_Item_ID | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| Item_ID      | int(11)   | NO   |     |                   |                |
| Added_On     | timestamp | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+--------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

I'm only inserting to the Item_ID field which contains the ID of each item they bought (I'm populating the forms with item IDs). What I want to do is look up the item's name and price that's stored in the Inventory table. Here's how that looks:

```
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type           | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Inventory_ID | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| Item_Name    | varchar(40)    | NO   |     |                   |                |
| Item_Price   | float unsigned | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| Added_On     | timestamp      | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

So how would I pull out the Item_name and Item_Price fields from the Inventory table based on the Item_ID field from the temp table so I can display it on the page? I just don't understand how to formulate the query. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: you use a SELECT statement to describe the columns you want to return, a FROM clause to say where to get those columns, and a WHERE clause to say under what conditions.

Comment: why there is no item_id in the Inventory table?

Comment: As I understood: Inventory_ID and Item_ID is the same thing

Comment: @Slava But Inventory_ID is auto_increment

Comment: Right, you adding item Inventory_ID is incrementing, and when you selling something Cart_Item_ID is incrementing.

Comment: When you say "*table name is temp*", do you mean the table's name is actually `temp`, or that a temporary name is generated for each user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called `JOIN` - read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

```
SELECT Inventory.Item_Name, Inventory.Item_Price 
FROM Inventory, temp WHERE Inventory.Inventory_ID = temp.Item_ID
```

Comment: Hey, that's exactly what I was looking for. One more question: How would I get the total of that price. I tried this but recevied an error:

Comment: SELECT SUM(Inventory.Item_Price)
FROM Inventory, temp WHERE Inventory.Inventory_ID = temp.Item_ID

Answer (score 1):

what i understand is that the Item_ID in temp table is referencing to the Inventory_ID in inventory table. based on this assumption you can use the following query.

```
Select Item_Name, Item_Price from Inventory, Temp where Temp.Item_ID == Inventory.Inventory_ID
```

i guess this is what you want to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, you can't (unless Inventory_ID = Item_ID)

What you need is a way of JOINing the two tables together. In this instance, if Inventory_ID = Item_ID then the following is possible:

```
SELECT      Item_Name,
            Item_Price

FROM        InventoryTable
INNER JOIN  TempItemTable ON (InventoryTable.Inventory_ID = ItemTable.Item_ID)
```

If you want to filter for a particular item you can add the constraint:

```
WHERE ItemTable.Item_ID = 27 --for example
```

That will join all the rows in your inventory table with matching rows in the Item table.

Jeff Atwood has a [great](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) (IMO) visual explanation of how JOINs work.